# Is there a way to add parameters to macro list?

Tags: c++, macros

Here is the thing :

I have made this macro :

```
#define CREATE_FROM_LIST(ClassName, List) \
class ClassName##Vars \
{\
public :\
    List(CREATE_GET_SET) \
};

#define CREATE_GET_SET(Name, Type) \
Type get##Name##() {/***/} \
void set##Name##() {/***/}
```

My goal is to create a class that will handle all the get/set of a set of variables.

I have this piece of code in a file :

```
#define MY_VAR_LIST(var) \
var(foo1, float) \
var(foo2, int) \
var(foo3, char)

CREATE_FROM_LIST(FooManager, MY_VAR_LIST)
```

And I get the expected result when I expand the macro :

```
class FooManagerVars
{
public:
    float getfoo1() {/***/}
    void setfoo1() {/***/}
    /* same thing for foo2 and foo3*/
};
```

But now I would like to separate the definition and the declaration of the get/set methods. I would like to call one macro to create the class with the declarations, and another one to create the definitions.

My problem is that, in order to create the definitions, I need the ClassName :

```
Type ClassName##Vars::get##Name() {/***/}
```

But I cannot figure out how I can have the list parameters (Type, Name) and the ClassName at the same time without passing the ClassName as a parameter in all the vars of the list.

Comment: did you consider to make the members public? Honestly, I fail to see what you gain from getters and setters that do nothing but get/set the value (I suppose thats what `/***/` stands for).

Comment: I simplified it in order to make it clear, but the get/set are interacting with the register, using some information (like register keys) that are stored in the class. Having this class system is also a way to order my variables in different classes.

Comment: thanks for explaning. Anyhow, the question isnt about generating getters/setters in essence, it could use a completely different example, and the question would be the same

Comment: Why? What is the aim? Please first explain rationale why you need this feature. It would be nice to see what you are doing now manually (before macros) then explain why you need replace this with macros.

Comment: Use boost::preprocessor.